# Add rectangle into pdfpcell itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext, cell, rectangles

How can I add a rectangle with certain width, height and background color into a PdfPCell using itextsharp?

Something like this:

```
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    rectangle.Width = 50f;
                    rectangle.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.RED;

                    cell.AddElement(cell);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: draw the `Rectangle` as a Form XObject (`PdfTemplate`), wrap it inside an `Image` object, and add that image to the table.

However: there are several ways to do this, and there may be only one way that results in the desired output. That's why I've made you an example: [rectangle_in_cell.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/objects/cmp_rectangle_in_cell.pdf)

Take a close look at this PDF. In the top margin you see a line that measures 120 pt in length. In the different tables, you see three rectangles that were created as a rectangle measuring 120 by 80 pt. Only one rectangle seems to have the correct size.

When adding objects to a table, iText often resizes the content to make it fit into a cell. The [RectangleInCell](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext5-building-blocks/rectangle-examples#1314-rectangleincell.java) example shows you the differences in code between the three approaches. It's written in Java, but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it to C#.

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks a lot!